# How can I extract the 'x' axis of from a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, librosa

I try to plot the graph with this code:

```
db = librosa.core.amplitude_to_db(y)

plt.title('Noise level')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Volume, db')
plt.plot(db)
```

As a result I got such graph:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4m6M.png].

Otherwise, I should plot the graph in *time* for `x` axis and *db* in `y` axis. What should I do to achieve that?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here. What is the desired result? How does it differ from what you're getting? It appears to me that the x-axis may already be time, just in seconds or microseconds, so I'm not sure what your last statement there is asking.

Comment: You are right but I can't extract time numpy array. Numpy array that 'x' consists - desired result is

Comment: There is no problem description in the question. The comment "desired result is –" does not make that any clearer. Voting to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a `time` vector if you do not have one already. If you have one you can use it directly. In the example below, I created a simple time from 0 with a timestep of 0.1.

```
    dt = 0.1
    t = np.arange(0,dt*db.size-dt, dt)
    plt.plot(t, db)
```

Comment: I have updated the time vector to be more general and it now will depend on your db size (it was 3 before). Does it work now?